# Как защитить сеть от взлома Wi-Fi?

Tags: безопасность, защита

Если кто-нибудь поставит Linux Kali, он 100% взломает мою точку доступа? Каким образом можно защититься именно от Kali?

Comment: он точно не взломает Ваш WiFi, если его выключить. По факту, лучше выключить  wps, поставить хорошие алгоритмы шифрования, настроить фильтрацию по макам. И регулярно проверять логи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На "скорую руку":

1. По возможности воздержаться от использования WPA
2. По возможности включить только и только WPA2
3. Сам бы пароль не придумывал, а доверился хорошему генератору паролей. Если лень запоминать на это есть KeaPass-подобные программы
4. Длина пароля не критично, главное не менее 12. (1)
5. Ну и сделал еще скрытой
6. Регулярно следить за прошивкой

(1) Ни где в WiFi-протоколе не указывается длина пароля! А значит злоумышленник должен подсмотреть как вводится пароль. Передаются только и только хэши.

Существующие средства по взлому WiFi работают так:

1. Дампят ВЕСЬ WiFi-трафик
2. Подают программам которые извлекают "рукопожатия" из дампа
3. На основе этих извлеченных дампов можно вести подбор пароля

Comment: WPA2 уже стоит) пароль из 32 символов. Нормально?

Comment: А я вот сколько читал про безапасность паролей, создается впечатление, что лучше придумывать самому, т.к. некоторые генераторы - откровенная лажа и подбор пароля ускоряется, 32 символа - более чем :)

Comment: А при "рукопожатии" нет сведений о длине пароля! Как вывод нет возможности угодать более точное правило для подбора пароля. Если не трепишься соседям, а при вводя в интерфейсах либо "звездочки" либо пусто, как при вводе пароля, то любой больше 10 символов сгодится

Comment: Скрытой сеть делать не надо. Это наоборот привлечет внимание тех, кто будет сканировать наличие wi-fi рядом с вами. Если в пароле доступны пробелы, то лучше задать не пароль, а паролевую фразу. P.S. У меня пароль более 64 символов :Р